# Trying to read in text line by line from a text file and output to a new text file reformatted

Tags: c++

So I am trying to read the text in from file a. The text is in groups of three

Name
Country
Score( 1 2 3 4 5) which can be any random number and in any order

At this point I am having issues reading in the text into separate arrays

So far I have this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char* thePlayer[20];
    char* theCountry[20];
    char* theScore[100];

    fstream myInputFile("playerData.txt");
    fstream myOutputFile;

    // int highestRank = computeHighestRank();

    // myInputFile.open("playerData",    ios::in);
    // myOutputFile.open("playerReport", ios::out);

    myInputFile.open("playerData.txt"); //, ios::in);

    int theCount = 1;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;

while (! myInputFile.eof()) {


        myInputFile.getline << (thePlayer[i], theCount, '\n');
        theCount++;
        myInputFile.getline << (theCountry[j], theCount, '\n');
        theCount++;
        myInputFile.getline << (theScore[k], theCount, '\n');
        theCount + 2;
        cout << thePlayer[i] << endl;
        cout << theCountry[j] << endl;
        cout << theScore[k] << endl;
      }

    myOutputFile << "         1         2         3         4         5         6" << "\n\n" << "123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890" << "\n\n" << "Player             Country             Highest Rank         " << "\n\n" << "------------------------------------------------------------" << "\n\n";

int computeHighestRank()
{

}
```

Which gives me this error. Any ideas would be appreciate it.

> Error 1   error C3867: `'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::getline'`: function call missing argument list; use `'&std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::getline'` to create a pointer to member `c:\users\justin\desktop\lab 7\lab 7\lab7source.cpp`    71

Comment: Try `std::getline`, and free yourself from C-strings.  :P

Comment: Oh, and you'll make your life a lot simpler if you say `struct Player { std::string name, country, score; };`, and fill a `std::vector<Player>`  rather than farting around with three separate raw arrays.

Comment: `while (! myInputFile.eof())` is wrong. Who taught you to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That one's pretty self explanatory when you read it. You have no argument list, [getline(args)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/), for getline.

Also, please get used to searching for errors like [C3867](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0x1aatf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) yourself, it will actually save you some time as there are generally exhaustive examples of *every* possible cause for them.

Answer (score 1):

Well, basically it's right there in th e error message; getline is a function, not a stream object. Thus replace

```
myInputFile.getline << (thePlayer[i], theCount, '\n');
```

with

```
myInputFile.getline(thePlayer[i], theCount, '\n');
```

and you should be one step closer. But what you really want to do is probably more like letting thePlayer, theCountry and theScore be of type std::string and

```
myInputFile >> thePlayer >> theCountry >> theScore;
```

Comment: The extraction operator would only get one word into each string.  If a value could contain spaces, `getline` is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Read about getline function here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/

You have an array of character pointers but space is not allocated for storing the strings themselves.  Even if you manage to compile your code, you will end up in crashing your application. You will be better off using string class.

Also you are not incrementing i,j,k which will overwrite the same locations.
The second argument in getline is supposed to be the max size to read from input stream so instead of theCount it should be a bigger number.